# append text file with vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am  trying to achieve a simple objective,insert row count and column count summary of an excel file to an existing notepad.

I have multiple files in a folder and would like to run this operation for each file and send the details to a notepad.

**Issue**: Every time i run the code it deletes existing content and inserts new data into the notepad. I would like to retain existing data and start appending from a new line

code:

```
  Sub Sndtotxt()
  Dim FF
  Dim rCnt AS INTEGER
  Dim cCnt AS INTEGER

  rCnt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
  cCnt = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

  FF = FreeFile()
  OPEN "C:\Temp files\summaryreport.txt" FOR Output AS #FF
  Print #FF, rCnt
  Print #FF, cCnt

  CLOSE #FF
  END Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

`OPEN "C:\Temp files\summaryreport.txt" FOR Output AS #FF`
with
`OPEN "C:\Temp files\summaryreport.txt" FOR Append AS #FF`

In terms of looping through files in a folder, suggest you start with my code from [Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Change the path below for both

- Excel files `C:\temp\`
- Txt report `C:\Temp\test.txt`

to suit

```
  Sub GetEm()
  Dim WB As Workbook
  Dim StrFile As String
  Dim FF

  FF = FreeFile()
  Open "C:\Temp\test.txt" For Append As #FF

  StrFile = Dir("c:\temp\*.xls*")
  Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
  Set WB = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\" & StrFile)
        StrFile = Dir
        Print #FF, WB.Name, WB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count, WB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Columns.Count
        WB.Close
  Loop
  Close #FF
  End Sub
```